# No incremental compile snapshot data available gradle error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am launching a Gradle task and it gives me an error like `No incremental compile snapshot data available`. I've searched online and I can't find a sufficient description for this. Do you know what exactly raises this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What gradle version are you using, found an old bug in v4.10: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6612

Answer (score 1):

My project is using gradle 4.10 version. However, gradlew.bat clean build --refresh-dependencies solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

**By Deleting the .gradle folder of Android Project**.

Then do gradle sync and build apk.

It will solve this problem